# Java UnsupportedClassVersionError Issue

Tags: java, unsupported-class-version

I understand the UnsupportedClassVersionError to be caused when I compile my java files in a newer version than the JVM the class file will be run on.

I'm working on a program that will run on an IBM i Series box, which is running Java 1.6. I've cross-compiled my files to use 1.5 for the source and target values. The actual command used is:

```
javac -source 1.5 -target 1.5 -bootclasspath C:/dev/languages/java/jdk1.5.0_22/jre/lib/rt.jar -extdirs "" -classpath "c:/dev/QIBM/ProdData/OS400/jt400/lib/*;/psmssys/java/src/com/gy/as400/common;." $(find ./com/gy/as400/bladder/install/* | grep .java)
```

Understand I am compiling the files on a Win 7 box running Java 1.8.0_131

Once the classes are compiled if I then run

```
javap -verbose
```

on any of the resulting classes, the Major Version shows 49which according to [this wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file#General_layout) should be compatible with JVM 1.5 and up.

I've tried to cross-compile to 1.4 but that would require me to rewite a significant portion of my code to not use `FOR...EACH` and generic lists.

What am I missing here.

Comment: The runtime environment is more important than how you compiled it here.  How are you invoking the code?

Comment: My program code is being invoked from a COBOL program. Everything resides on the IBM i Series box. We checked the runtime and it is running 1.6

Comment: Through a JNI interface or running a system command?

Comment: system command, currently. Eventually, it will execute from a sleeper job

Comment: If your runtime environment is Java 6, then you have something on your classpath that is getting invoked that is compiled for Java 7, 8, or 9.  The info above says you compiled your code for Java 5, so that's not it.  Are you using any non-JRE-provided libraries from your Java code?

Comment: That's what I would have thought as well. However, the only thing on the class path is a native JT400.jar coming from a system path. This is a very basic program that calls a remote stored procedure, formats the data and sends it off to another COBOL program.

Comment: I'd try invoking it from QShell to isolate COBOL out of it.  If it runs successfully there, then the COBOL invocation isn't giving you the Java level you think it is.  If it doesn't run successfully, then the Java stack trace should point to the line of code that is causing the unsupported class to be loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @rdean400.

I got to thinking and went back through my transfer logs and found some errors had occurred moving the class from my dev box to the test box. I cleared out all the existing class files and transferred them again. This resolved the UnsupportedClassVersionError.